# event session database design

Tags: database, database-design, erd

to make an event session, how'd you define a relationship.

Event has days, days has sessions. Days will hold the number of rows depending upon the number of days.

Should I be making 3 Tables or more?

```
1) Event Table (id, name)

2) Day Table (id, date, event_id)

3) Session Table (id, name, start_time, end_time, day_id)
```

or something different, please advise.

one event has multiple days, and each day has multiple sessions.

Edit: (is this okay)

```
event
id  name
1   event 1
2   event 2
-----
day
id  date            event_id
1   '2015-06-01'    1
2   '2015-06-02'    1
3   '2015-07-01'    2
4   '2015-07-02'    2
------
session
id  name        day_id
1   'session a'   1
2   'session b'   1
3   'session c'   2
4   'session d'   2
------
```

Comment: Too broad, depends on what you want to do with that data. Could you narrow down the use case ?

Comment: ok, let's say it's an event management system, first the master table to details of an event, and then event can be 3 day long, 4 day etc. and each day there will be sessions (speakers talking), and session has a start end time, All i wanted to ask if my 3 table design is correct?

Comment: for each day of the event there will be corresponding row to the record